# How can I check if there are any common bits between two bitmasks?

Tags: .net, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I am trying to find out if one bitmask has at least one of the same bits set as in another bitmask.  I couldn't seem to find a bitwise operator that does this, so I came up with this code that works, though I can't say I really like it.

```
[Flags]
enum TestFlags { a = 1, b = 2, c = 4, d = 8 }

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TestFlags
        bm1 = TestFlags.a | TestFlags.d,
        bm2 = TestFlags.b | TestFlags.c | TestFlags.d;

    var SetFlags = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TestFlags))
        .Cast<TestFlags>()
        .Where(v => bm1.HasFlag(v));

    foreach (var e in SetFlags.Where(f => bm2.HasFlag(f)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

Is there any more elegant way to perform this check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just use the [bitwise-AND operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c.aspx) (`&`):

```
var bm3 = bm1 & bm2; // TestFlags.d
```

This will return a new value which has a flag set for every bit that was set in both `bm1` and `bm2`.

And if you want to see if *any* bits are set in this new value, you can just compare it to `0`:

```
Console.WriteLine(bm3 != 0); // True
```

Comment: This solution was so simple that I am ashamed of myself.  Maybe if I had a better understanding of the mechanics behind bitwise operations, I would have known the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the *and* operator and compare the result to zero, for example:

```
(bm1 & bm2) != 0
```

If it's *true*, then they have at least 1 bit in common.

Comment: Does that work if they both have the most significant bit set?

Comment: @harold Nice catch, I've changed my answer to `!=` instead of `>`. That should do the trick :-)